# SOMBRAS EN LETRAS (CSS)

Tags: html, css

espero que todos se encuentren bien, mi pregunta es como se le pueden poner sombras a las letras? hasta el momento he encontrado solamente al fondo(background) pero no a letras propiamente tal.
El que responda de antemano le agradezco UwU

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para que tu pregunta no termine cerrada, debes mostrar lo que has intentado. La idea del sitio es formular preguntas concretas, donde se demuestre el trabajo / esfuerzo / investigación realizada y el intento por resolver la situación. Actualmente tu pregunta no cumple ese formato. De hecho es duplicada de [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/373792/c%C3%B3mo-se-puede-hacer-sombra-alargada-con-css) pregunta, donde hay respuestas que indican cómo añadir sombra al texto usando CSS. Saludos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo se puede hacer sombra alargada con CSS?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/373792/c%c3%b3mo-se-puede-hacer-sombra-alargada-con-css)

Answer (score 4):

La propiedad de CSS se llama asi "text-shadow"

Aqui puedes encontrar (en ingles) especificacion de su uso:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

La propiedad que hacer el efecto 3d es text-shadow.
La parte de los 2px es los pixeles de entrada y el color de sobra, despues los demas de 4px es para hacer un poco el efecto de 3d y los 6px es para que ya se vea en 3d

```css
h1 {
 height: 10vh;
 text-shadow:2px 2px 4px #FFF, 4px 4px 4px #111,
 6px 6px 4px #222;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hola Caracola</h1>
```

https://html-css-js.com/css/generator/text-shadow/ en esta pagina puedes contemplar y editar el text-shadow para ver como quedaria

Comment: listo mucho mejor?

Comment: como lo ves BetaM

Comment: también voy a intentar explicarlo

Answer (score 3):

La propiedad css para la sombra en el texto es: `text-shadow`

**La sintaxis es:**

*offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | color*

text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;

Puedes agregar varias sombras separadas por comas para dar un efecto de 3d.

```css
body {
  background-color: #e7e5e4;
  text-align: center;
}

.shadow {
  font-family: 'arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #131313;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  text-shadow: 1px -1px 0 #767676, -1px 2px 1px #737272, -2px 4px 1px #767474, -3px 6px 1px #787777, -4px 8px 1px #7b7a7a, -5px 10px 1px #7f7d7d, -6px 12px 1px #828181, -7px 14px 1px #868585, -8px 16px 1px #8b8a89, -9px 18px 1px #8f8e8d, -10px 20px 1px #949392, -11px 22px 1px #999897, -12px 24px 1px #9e9c9c, -13px 26px 1px #a3a1a1, -14px 28px 1px #a8a6a6, -15px 30px 1px #adabab, -16px 32px 1px #b2b1b0, -17px 34px 1px #b7b6b5, -18px 36px 1px #bcbbba, -19px 38px 1px #c1bfbf, -20px 40px 1px #c6c4c4, -21px 42px 1px #cbc9c8, -22px 44px 1px #cfcdcd, -23px 46px 1px #d4d2d1, -24px 48px 1px #d8d6d5, -25px 50px 1px #dbdad9, -26px 52px 1px #dfdddc, -27px 54px 1px #e2e0df, -28px 56px 1px #e4e3e2;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="shadow">TEXT SHADOW</h1>
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, serviría de mucho que agregues una explicación de lo que hace cada parámetro.